# Select different number of records by group

Tags: mysql

I have a database in which each record has a `grade` and is associated to a certain `group`. 
I need to select the best `grades` in each `group`, not the usual top 5, but a different number in each `group`.

In the following example, there are `10 records` and `two groups`- `A` and `B`.

I want the highest 2 grades in `group A` and the highest 3 in `group B`:

```
ID  Group   Grade
1     A      4
2     B      2
3     B      4
4     A      7
5     A      8
6     A      5
7     B     10
8     B      3
9     B      9
10    A      7
```

The query should select records 4 and 5 of group A and records 3, 7 and 9 in group B.

I will appreciate any ideas to make this query.

Regards

Comment: I would caution against using reserved words as table/column identifiers.

Comment: I would simply do `UNION` of selects in single groups. Like `SELECT <top 2 in group A> UNION SELECT <top 3 in group B> UNION ...`

Comment: @RomanHocke You'd have to make them in to subqueries for that to work.

Comment: also `TOP` is SQL Server (MSSQL) @RomanHocke MySQL uses `LIMIT`

Comment: Unimportant details. The point is - I would select result for groups A and B separately and then union them into single result (if this is desired form of result).

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 groups, but with a different top N?

Then I guess a union with 2 limits could do the job in a MySql 5.* version.

```
SELECT ID, `Group`, Grade
FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM YourTable 
   WHERE `Group` = 'A' 
   ORDER BY Grade DESC, ID ASC
   LIMIT 2
) A
UNION ALL
SELECT ID, `Group`, Grade
FROM 
(
   SELECT * FROM YourTable 
   WHERE `Group` = 'B' 
   ORDER BY Grade DESC, ID ASC
   LIMIT 3
) B
ORDER BY `Group`, Grade DESC, ID;
```

Result:

```
ID  Group   Grade
5   A       8
4   A       7
7   B       10
9   B       9
3   B       4
```

In MySql 8 you could use the ROW_NUMBER or the DENSE_RANK functions for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have 1.5 millon records an 2400 groups. Is there a way to make a sort of loop in the query?

Comment: In MySql 8 you have more options, like Recursive CTE's which is the closest to a loop in a Query.   And also the window functions like ROW_NUMBER. But I'm guessing you're still on a 5.*   However, one can use variables to simulate ROW_NUMBER.  Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54727853/4003419) previous answer of mine.  Once you have a rank per `Group`, you can use it.  f.e. `WHERE rnk <= 3`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will chek this out

Answer (score 0):

You can

- **group by** the **Group column** and
- use **subqueries** to get the best grade ids that you want

eg:

```
SELECT s1.`group` AS groupId1,  (
    SELECT id
    FROM `students` s2
    WHERE s2.`group` = s1.`group`
    ORDER BY s2.grade DESC, s2.id ASC
    LIMIT 0,1
 ) AS bestGradeId,  (
    SELECT id
    FROM `students` s2
    WHERE s2.`group` = s1.`group`
    ORDER BY s2.grade DESC, s2.id ASC
    LIMIT 1,1
 ) AS best2GradeId,  (
    SELECT id
    FROM `students` s2
    WHERE s2.`group` = s1.`group`
    ORDER BY s2.grade DESC, s2.id ASC
    LIMIT 2,1
 ) AS best3GradeId
FROM `students` s1
GROUP BY s1.`group`
```